# How to use Google Drive server key in java

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I have a code snippet to connect to google drive from a client it works fine on a desktop with a browser.

```
public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = DriveQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets
                = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow
            = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                    HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
            flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    System.out.println(
            "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
    return credential;
}

/**
 * Build and return an authorized Drive client service.
 *
 * @return an authorized Drive client service
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static Drive getDriveService() throws IOException {
    Credential credential = authorize();
    return new Drive.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
}
```

this code opens the default browser and prompts the user to

> allow or deny

access to the drive and stores the credentials on the local repository.

I am not able to run this on a Linux machine (no browser and wget also fails)
Should I use OAuth or go for API Key (Server key) or any other approach to resolve this.

Comment: In Linux which browser are you using and may be there is proxy issue, need to check without proxy

Comment: Are you implementing this based on the [Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java) of Drive API? If you want to perform web authorization, its suggested that you use [OAuth2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer)

Comment: I have a csv file that is generated on Rhel (oracle db generates the file).and I am trying to upload the same to google drive. simple standalone java utility to upload the file.

Comment: I'm not sure if this can help, but you can try out [Service Accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) which will act like a middleware. Since the Linux machine is headless, your web server will use the .csv that will interact with the Service Account - hopefully this will upload the file to Drive.